# Wavefunction of electron leaving and diffracting from a moving tube

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, diffraction

Say you have a wavefunction $\Psi(x,y,t)$ that represents an electron going down an impenetrable tube of radius $r$, and length $l$,  that's moving along the $x$ axis, left to right, with the exit of the tube moving along the line $y = 0$, and the particle is propagating through the tube, how can one obtain an expression for the wavefunction when it escapes the in-motion tube? Can one treat it like a fluid with the probability flux, and if so, how? Can this be generalised to non-linear motion?

Comment: If the tube is moving with constant velocity, what difference does this make to the electron?

Comment: Because once it leaves the tube, would it make a continuously changing diffraction pattern?

Comment: If the wave has some appreciable 'length' when it's in the tube

Comment: Oh I see your point, I don't necessarily mean to state the tube is at constant velocity, just that it's moving in a line.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if the tube is not moving?